# MySql insert bit using tab delimited

Tags: mysql

I am using a tab delimited file to insert data into MySql database

in bit field I got 0 and 1 as a value but when I insert the data into the database using the command below it is converting 0 to 1.

```
load data local infile 'c:/membership.txt' into table membership;
```

as a result the bit column on has value 1 in every row.

Structure of table is

```
       Create table Membership
    (
    MemberShipId int not null AUTO_INCREMENT, 
StartDate datetime not null, 
EndDate datetime not null, 
AgeGroup tinyint, 
Newsletter bit, 
Donation decimal(7,2), 
FavouriteShow varchar(50), 
Comments varchar(200), 
MemberId int not null, 
PRIMARY KEY (MemberShipId),
CONSTRAINT fk_Member FOREIGN KEY (MemberId) REFERENCES Member (MemberId)
    );
```

sample input is

```
1   2012-01-01  2012-01-01  0   0   \N  \N  1
2   2012-01-01  2012-01-01  1   0   \N  \N  2
3   2012-01-01  2012-01-01  1   0   \N  \N  3
4   2012-01-01  2012-01-01  1   0   \N  \N  4
5   2012-01-01  2012-01-01  0   0   \N  \N  5
6   2012-01-01  2012-01-01  0   0   \N  \N  6
```

Comment: What does your input data look like?

Comment: Please post the structure of the "membership" table and a few sample lines of the membership.txt file.

Comment: @Michael please check updates

Comment: @KillerGearz earlier versions of MySQL interpreted `bit` as `tinyint(1)` but newer versions actually have a binary `bit` type. Try defining your table as `Newsletter TINYINT(1)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When importing the CSV file, it seems your values are being implicitly quoted as strings.  When using a `BIT` type in MySQL after 5.0.3, it is intended as a bit field (like '11001' for example), not as a boolean type 1/0.  The string values `'0'` and `'1'` both seem to be interpreted as non-empty data, and you don't just get a 0.

Instead, you can use a `TINYINT(1)` type or its synonym `BOOLEAN`, which will support only the numeric values 1 or 0.

```
Create table Membership
(
  MemberShipId int not null AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  StartDate datetime not null, 
  EndDate datetime not null, 
  AgeGroup TINYINT,
  /* use TINYINT(1) for a boolean  OR use BOOLEAN */ 
  Newsletter TINYINT(1), 
  Donation decimal(7,2), 
  FavouriteShow varchar(50), 
  Comments varchar(200), 
  MemberId int not null, 
  PRIMARY KEY (MemberShipId),
  CONSTRAINT fk_Member FOREIGN KEY (MemberId) REFERENCES Member (MemberId)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The MySql documentation appears to cover this problem:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html

See about halfway down the page at the section starting with:

> BIT values cannot be loaded using binary notation ...

A somewhat clumsy workaround is described.